# c++ class function friend to another class

Tags: c++, class, friend, friend-function

I'm trying to specify a class member function as a friend of another class,
but it gives me only access to the public members not the protected or private members. It's working fine with free functions.

Visual Studio Errors:

```
member "Class1::protected_int" (declared at line 9) is inaccessible
member "Class1::private_int" (declared at line 11) is inaccessible
```

```
class Class2;

class Class1 {
    friend void Class2::TEST(const Class1& ex);
    friend void TEST(const Class1& ex);

public:
    int public_int;
protected:
    int protected_int;
private:
    int private_int;
};

class Class2{
public:
    void TEST(const Class1& ex);
};

void Class2::TEST(const Class1& ex){
    int pub = ex.public_int;
    int pro = ex.protected_int;
    int pri = ex.private_int;
}

void TEST(const Class1& ex){
    int pub = ex.public_int;
    int pro = ex.protected_int;
    int pri = ex.private_int;
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4O5M.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program is already ill-formed here:

```
friend void Class2::TEST(const Class1& ex);
```

`Class2` is incomplete, so you cannot access members of it yet. If you reorder your code such that everything is complete when it needs to be:

```
class Class1;

class Class2{
public:
    void TEST(const Class1& ex);
};

class Class1{
    friend void Class2::TEST(const Class1& ex);
    friend void TEST(const Class1& ex);

    // ...
};
```

then everything compiles fine.

Comment: This is what I found myself as well; however, this does not help when there's 'circular friendship' between `Class1` and `Class2`..